# How to Add a 2nd Criteria to an Index Match Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know this has been asked before, but I'm not able to make sense of other people's examples.

Here is a formula I have that works:

```
=INDEX('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$E$2:$E$5000,MATCH(LARGE('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000,1),'[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000,0))
```

It looks at the AL DOE sheet and returns the school name (column E) that has the highest percentage of members (column L).

Now I want to have it look for the highest percentage of members among primary schools.  This info is in column P.

This is what I tried:

```
=INDEX('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$E$2:$E$5000,MATCH(LARGE('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000,1),('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000) * ('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!Primary=$P$2:$P$5000),0))
```

It gives me a #N/A error.  Here is an example of the data:

```
-------E-------------------------------L-----------------------P
------School--------------------Percent Members----------School Level
John E. Bryan Elem Sch PTA------------84%------------------Primary
Goldsmith Schiffman Elementary PTA----21%------------------Primary
Huntsville Hi Sch PTSA----------------96%--------------------High 
Bernice Causey Middle PTSA------------54%-------------------Middle
Hampton Cove Elem PTA-----------------34%------------------Primary
Elsie Collier Elem PTA----------------78%------------------Primary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a few different bits going wrong on your new formula but you've almost got it.

The first bit is the LARGE formula; currently it will still be returning 96% as there is nothing on that restricts this function to Primary only. This bit should be something like

```
LARGE(IF('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$P$2:$P$5000' = "Primary", [AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000),1)
```

This says to looks for the largest value in L but only in the rows where P is "Primary". This would now return 84% and feed into your MATCH part of the query but there's an issue there. At he endo fo your formula you currently have:

```
('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!Primary=$P$2:$P$5000)
```

when it should be

```
('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$P$2:$P$5000 = "Primary")
```

So this would give you a final formula of

```
=INDEX('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$E$2:$E$5000,MATCH(LARGE(IF('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$P$2:$P$5000 = "Primary", '[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000),1), ('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$L$2:$L$5000) * ('[AL DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$P$2:$P$5000 = "Primary"),0))
```

You also needs this to be an array formula so after typing it in you'll need to press Ctrl, Shift & Enter together

Comment: Awesome!  That worked!  I made two small edits to your final formula (you forgot an apostrophe and forgot to fix the Primary=$P$2:$P$5000 at the end, but otherwise it worked like a charm.  Thank you!