# Properly Display Tie in an Index Match Ranked Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Last month I got an [excellent formula](https://superuser.com/questions/1394250/how-to-add-a-2nd-criteria-to-an-index-match-formula) that returned the primary, middle or high school with the highest percentage of PTA members (and 2nd highest, etc).  I just ran into a problem with ties.

Here is the formula I have:

```
=INDEX('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$B$2:$B$5000,MATCH(LARGE(IF('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$M$2:$M$5000 = "PRIMARY", '[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$I$2:$I$5000),1), ('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$I$2:$I$5000) * ('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$M$2:$M$5000 = "Primary"),0))
```

Here is some example data:

```
-------B-------------------------------I-----------------------M
------School--------------------Percent Members----------School Level
John E. Bryan Elem Sch PTA------------84%------------------Primary
Goldsmith Schiffman Elementary PTA----34%------------------Primary
Huntsville Hi Sch PTSA----------------96%--------------------High 
Bernice Causey Elem   PTSA------------34%------------------Primary
Hampton Cove Elem PTA-----------------34%------------------Primary
Highland Middle School----------------42%-------------------Middle
Elsie Collier Elem PTA----------------24%------------------Primary
```

It should rank them like this:

```
1st - John E Bryan Elem Sch PTA
2nd - Goldsmith Schiffman Elementary PTA
3rd - Bernice Cousey Elem PTSA
4th - Hampton Cove Elem PTA
5th - Elise Collier Elem PTA
```

But it incorrectly does this:

```
1st - John E Bryan Elem Sch PTA
2nd - Goldsmith Schiffman Elementary PTA
3rd - Goldsmith Schiffman Elementary PTA
4th - Goldsmith Schiffman Elementary PTA
5th - Elise Collier Elem PTA
```

Help?

Comment: It looks like your example is just for Primary schools?  Actually, what you show as "correct" isn't.  There is a three-way tie, so 1st is correct, then there should be three 2nds (your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th should all be 2nd), then 5th is correct.

Comment: Yea, but that's just a labeling issue.  Whether they are listed as 2nd, 2nd, 2nd or 2nd, 3rd, 4th, doesn't matter much for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper column that adds a tie-breaking value to your percentage.  Since your example data shows `M` as the last column, I have selected column `N` as the helper column.  Just make it the next column after your data and you can hide it after you get this set up.

In cell `N2` enter `=0.001-(ROW()/100000000)+I2` and drag it down at least as many rows as schools you will ever have.

This assumes that you don't need any of the decimal places in your percentages, which is what it looks like in your example.

`ROW()` returns the row number the formula is on.  That is divided by `100,000,000` and subtracted from `0.001`.  This will give you a number starting at`0.099998` and decreasing towards `0.000001`.  That way the tie-breaker will favor the order that they are listed in, such that in your case "Goldsmith Schiffman" will be listed as the first and "Hampton Cove" as the last in that series of ties. These values were arbitrarily selected to not round up a percentage point and to give you a large enough set of tie-breakers, assuming that you would be unlikely to have more than `99,998` schools to track.

Adding this tie-breaker number to your percentage ensures that there is no tie.  In this case you would end up with these values to rank:

```
| School                               | Helper Col |
|--------------------------------------|------------|
| Goldsmith Schiffman   Elementary PTA | 34.099997% |
| Bernice Causey Elem   PTSA           | 34.099995% |
| Hampton Cove Elem PTA                | 34.099994% |
```

And you would modify your formula to this:

`=INDEX('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$B$2:$B$5000,MATCH(LARGE(IF('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$M$2:$M$5000 = "PRIMARY", '[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$N$2:$N$5000),1), ('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$N$2:$N$5000) * ('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$M$2:$M$5000 = "Primary"),0))`

changing all of your references from column `I` to column `N`, or whatever column you decide to put your helper column.  Of course, you still need to enter this as a `CSE` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of adding a helper column to calculate the Rank, with adjustments for duplicates, would be:

```
J2: =RANK(I2,$I$2:$I$8, 1)+COUNTIF($I$2:I2,I2)-1
```

and fill down as far as needed.

The `COUNTIF(…)-1` function creates the unique rank, by adding the number of duplicates found "so far" as you fill down. Note also that the highest rank will be the highest number.

[image]

Assuming the Workbook is open and the formula is on the same worksheet, the following formula will return the School name corresponding to the unique rank we generated in the helper column:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5000,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,4,($M$2:$M$5000="PRIMARY")*($J$2:$J$5000),Q2),$J$2:$J$5000,0))
```

[image]

If I have edited the formula correctly, the following includes the workbook/worksheet references you show in your original:

```
=INDEX('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$B$2:$B$5000,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,4,('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$M$2:$M$5000="PRIMARY")*('[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$J$2:$J$5000),Q2),'[OK DOE.xlsx]DOE'!$J$2:$J$5000,0))
```

Change `Q2` to refer to the cell that contains the desired rank for the school you are going to return.

Note that, with this formula, the primary schools at 34% are listed in reverse order from what you show in your example.  If that is an issue, other logic can be added but, since they are all technically the same rank, the order should be irrelevant.

Comment: If you use this method, you need to change the `LARGE` to `SMALL` in the `CSE` formula.

Comment: @ReyJuna 1. Thanks.  I changed the rank order argument in the formula and forgot to edit.