# How to add a 3rd criterion to an index match large formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ok, I feel a little silly since [two years ago I asked about adding a 2nd criterion](https://superuser.com/questions/1394250/how-to-add-a-2nd-criteria-to-an-index-match-formula/1394417#1394417) to this formula, and now I'm adding a third and I'm stumped again.

The three criteria I'm looking to match are:

- I want to match the state (listed in $A$2 of the local sheet) in column G in the data sheet.
- I want to match the school type (hard coded, "elementary" in this case) in column Q in the data sheet.
- I want to match the largest number in column BF in the data sheet.

Here is the data I'm pulling from:
[image]

The rank helper column breaks any ties in the data.

And here is the report sheet where the information is going (it is in a separate spreadsheet):
[image]

So D46 in the report sheet would show the name of the AZ elementary school with the highest percentage of membership (BF).  D47 would show the name of the AZ elementary school with the second highest percentage of membership, etc.

Here is my working formula that shows the largest number and state:

```
=INDEX('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$A$2:$A$40000,MATCH(LARGE(IF('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$G$2:$G$40000=$A$2,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BF$2:$BF$40000),4),IF('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$G$2:$G$40000=$A$2,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BF$2:$BF$40000),0))
```

Now I'd like for it to also check the school type (i.e. "elementary")  I tried it two ways, neither worked.

First I thought I'd change the IF function to an IFS function and add another criteria.  No dice:

```
=INDEX('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$A$2:$A$40000,MATCH(LARGE(IFS('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$G$2:$G$4000=$A$2,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BF$2:$BF$4000,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$Q$2:$Q$4000="Elementary",'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BF$2:$BF$4000),2),IFS('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$G$2:$G$4000=$A$2,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BF$2:$BF$4000,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$Q$2:$Q$4000="Elementary",'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BF$2:$BF$4000),0)
```

Then I tried using two IF functions:

```
=INDEX('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$A$2:$A$4000,MATCH(LARGE(IF('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$G$2:$G$4000=$A$2,'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BG$2:$BG$4000) * IF('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$Q$2:$Q$4000="Elementary",'[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BG$2:$BG$4000),2),('[DOE Data.xlsx]Data'!$BG$2:$BG$4000),0))
```

Still didn't work.  Clearly I did something wrong.  Both formulas just give me #N/A.  Help?

Comment: Criterion singular, criteria plural.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Professional Plus 2016

Comment: A relevant sample of your data would be useful in crafting a solution.

Comment: Ok, sample data added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to suggest an array (CSE) formula, extracts multiple rows based on three criteria.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$25, LARGE(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$25,$A$1)*COUNTIF($B$2:$B$25,$B$1)*COUNTIF($C$2:$C$25,$C$1), ROW($A$2:$C$25)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$C$25))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**N.B.**

- Instead of using Criteria like this "Elementary" (which makes the formula a Hard core), better use cell references for criterion, which make the Formula Dynamic.
- And gives you liberty, that if and when you need to change criteria then edit the cells contains criteria, rather than the formula.
- Cell A1,B1 and C1 contains criteria.
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and fill across.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

---

**:Edited:**

- *This part is based on screen shot recently OP has posted, where OP wants to get 5 largest percentage for Elementary Schools in state of Arizona.*
- To fix the issue OP's original formula needs little corrections.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter Value (*1 to 5*) in Helper Column
  G, as shown in attached screen shot.
- Value 1 to 5 are supporting the formula to get 5 largest value, works as array for LARGE Function.
- An array (CSE) formula in cell A174:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(A$165:A$170,MATCH(LARGE(IF($C$165:$C$170=$A$172,IF($F$165:$F$170="Elementary",$E$165:$E$170)),$G181),IF($C$165:$C$170=$A$172,$E$165:$E$170),0)),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and fill across.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: One criterion is dynamic, but the others need to be hard.  Either way though, when I tried your formula it just gave me the name (in column A) that had the highest row number and seems to ignore the other criteria.  I want to show the name (column A) of the school with the highest membership (column BH).  I'll be clearer about my criteria in my question above.

Comment: @OzzyKP,,, since formula works with 3 criteria then it may sometimes returns the unexpected Row/data, doesn't  matters whether you work with Hard core,, [edit] your post and share some sample data you are working with along with expected results,, help us to understand your need in better way !

Comment: Ok, I added the example data and expected results.  Thanks!

Comment: @OzzyKP,,now check the edited part of my post ,, solves the issue. And I'm sure this is what you were trying so far !.

Comment: Hooray, it worked!!!  Woo-hoo, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help you @OzzyKP ,,, keep asking ☺